# What may be difference between two code for pattern printing resulting same pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x, logic

I have to print below patter.

```
1                 1 
1 2             2 1 
1 2 3         3 2 1 
1 2 3 4     4 3 2 1 
1 2 3 4 5 5 4 3 2 1
```

when I use following code printing same pattern but the answer is not acceptable because **new line**

```
for i in range(1, N + 1):
    val = ''
    for j in range(1, i + 1):
        val += ' ' + str(j)
    val = val.strip()
    val += '  ' * (N - i)

    print(val,val[::-1])
```

output is same but showing output difference as-
[image]

when i uses follow code everything is okay and all test cases passed-

```
for i in range(1,N+1):
    for j in range(1,1+i):
        print(j,end=' ')
    print('  '*(N-i),end='')

    print('  '*(N-i),end='')
    for j in range(i,0,-1):
        print(j,end=' ')
    print()
```

where am i doing mistake?

Comment: Can't reproduce, both code samples produce same output.

Comment: yeah, both code produce same output but..... how output difference come??

Comment: No, they do not. There are extra spaces at the end of each line with the second code.

Comment: but online ide accepted the second code but not first code

Answer (score 0):

Not really a python question. More a question about the validator you are submitting your code to.

But, indeed, your 2 codes are not producing exactly the same result.
The first one is better in my view.
The secoond (and, apparently the one of the teacher who created the validator) add an extra space to each line. Which shows either by using a tool like `| hexdump -C` to inspect exact output.
Or by looking at the code: you were careful enough to avoid those spaces with correct usage of strip in the 1st code. When the second just write a space after each number, including the last one.

So if you ask me, the rejection of your first code was unfair (it is not only visually the same. But better. If you have a small terminal, with just enough width, that extra space may lead to pattern not rendering well when it should). So unfair. But, well, now your know the reason.